# UWP 6.2.2 and System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe Incompatibility

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, ef-core-2.2

I am fairly new to the UWP platform, and I'm having a bit of trouble trying to create my app package. The release build works fine, but when I try to make an app package for side-loading I get the following error.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll'. Source files: 
C:\Users\micha\.nuget\packages\runtime.win10-x64-aot.microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.2.2\runtimes\win10-x64-aot\lib\uap10.0.15138\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll
C:\Users\micha\.nuget\packages\system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe\4.5.1\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll   AN Solve-IT
```

It does seem that there are some dependencies in my project that contain the same class, but I'm not sure how to fix the problem.

In my project I have the following installed.

```
Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform 6.2.2
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite 2.2.0
Newtonsoft.JSON 12.0.1
```

I also have two supporting projects. One is a class library and the other is a migrations app. Combined they use the following.

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.2.0
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.0
NETStandard.Library 2.0.3
```

As I said above I can see there seems to be a file conflict in these two libraries, but I'm just not sure how to handle the issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

--- UPDATE ---

I followed the advice below which was to downgrade my UWP framework down to 2.1.9, but when I did that I get the following error.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       One of your dependencies requires the .NET Framework, but the .NET Framework could not be found in the NuGet packages installed in this project.  Please install the appropriate .NET Framework packages required by your dependency
```

I have verified that I have the .NET framework installed and it is referenced correctly in my project. I am able to do a local build and run on my machine. Any ideas as to what this could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downgrade your `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` package to the latest stable 6.1.9 as the current version you have was purged for [having an issue with it](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/issues/925).

Update:
Also downgrade other packages one-by-one if you get an error occured like the post mentioned.

Comment: It was purged? I just downloaded VS about a month ago. Do you know if it was rolled back since? I do appreciate the help and I'll give that a try and let you know if it works :)

Comment: Can you please see the update above. Strange things are happening now :(

Comment: Does it also produce the same error if you force the solution to restore nuget packages before build by enable `Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build.`?

Comment: Yes, that is enabled and the issue still occurs.

Comment: Either you try to clean and rebuild the solution, or repair VS,  there isn't much I can do since I've never encounter an error like that.

Comment: Hey Doe, so I finally figured out the issue. Your initial step was correct but I then also had to down-grade all of my MS frameworks for EF Core and anything else that was released after the UWP 6.2.2 release. Very annoying to say the least but finally got it figured out. Thanks!